# Rails 3.2.2 assets not working in production mode

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline

Disclaimer: I have looked all over but there are too many solutions to the problem which did not work for me hence this post.

Developed a simple website using Rails 3.2.2 in development mode got all assets working fine.  When I switched to use production (ie: rails server -e production), the assets breaks and I get the ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/stylesheets/application.css") error.

I haven't changed the production.rb file.

Thanks for helping this frustrated human being... :)

Answer (score 4):

You should [precompile the assets](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#precompiling-assets) before deploying the project.

```
bundle exec rake assets:precompile
```

Comment: Are stylesheets and scripts in the *public/* folder?

Comment: I see it in public/assets folder.  I tried to call http://localhost:3000/assets/application.css but I still get the RoutingError.

Answer (score 0):

In production.rb try `config.serve_static_assets = true`

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same issue. I forgot to add my files to config.assets.precompile...

[Rails assets working in development and not production](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23230799/rails-assets-working-in-development-and-not-production/23231022)

in my config/environments/production.rb I had to add a list of non default assets (like plugins)...

```
config.assets.precompile += w%( jquery.plugin.js awesome.css etc )
```